# Use GPIO for switchable Pullups of I2C

Tags: i2c, pullup

I'm designing a general purpose interface board and want to make available as many of the peripherals available and usable on an expansion header without the need for permanent (soldering) changes.

One issue is making the I2C pullup resistors switchable, such that they can be disabled when not needed. My initial idea simply uses a free GPIO output to pull the resistors high or is disabled (high impedance) when not needed, as depicted below. This apparently saves me a switch transistor. Is there anything I need to be aware of, or is this feasible?

I know that the pullup resistor values depends on the bus length and speed, but we found that for our applications 4k7 Ohm are generally OK.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzwjkb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Your use of a GPIO pin to pullup the the I2C bus resistor is a reasonable idea as long as the MCU in use has GPIOs that have a strong active high level output.

You will need to use two GPIOs, one for each resistor. If not then the two resistors are going to put 2x 4.7K ohms between the two signal lines.

So you have a tradeoff. Use two GPIOs for this or  one GPIO and two small switch FETs. Or you could equip each resistor with a two pin header and a jumper and use no GPIOs at all.

Comment: Why should I need two pins? Isn't the output basically a transistor connected between pin and supply? How is that different from a discrete switch?

Comment: @Arne: have a look at your schematics. You have 9.4kΩ between MOSI and MISO. Are you ok with that?

Comment: @Michael Huhh, sorry I've been blind... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty reasonable (especially if you use two lines, as @MichealKaras suggests, but I'd be concerned about the whole idea of letting the I2C bus float at all-- of course depending on what you're doing with the bus.  At the very least, I'd count on more testing and verification than I'd usually do to make sure that the bus comes back up smoothly.

Of course, it begs the question about why you need to disable the bus anyway.  If its just to save current, then I would consider pulling the bus high with some beefy resistors tied permanently high in parallel with your switched resistors, if you can spare some microamps.  That way your bus stays tied high during inactivity.

Comment: I don't want to have the I2C bus floating. When a I2C device is connected to the expansion connector the pullups shall be active. Only when for example the pins are used for SPI or GPIO the pullups are disabled to not interfere.

Comment: @Arne That's a different story.  Pretty miserly with your pins, though. My own inclination for a general purpose interface, though, would be to provide each bus and DIO.  Of course, it could be done, as it has on the BusPirate.  You might take a look at that design to see how it's been handles.  I believe the whole design is open.

Comment: "Pretty miserly" -- what do you mean?

Comment: @Arne -- I don't know what your cost and size constraints are, but there are some pretty big packages with high pin counts that would preclude the need to switch functionality.  You need to spend more, take up more board space, and use bigger connectors, of course, so it may not be the right choice.

Comment: Lack of connector space is exactly the constraint I need to circumvent. I'll have a look on available PMOS switches in suitable packages.